# Copying Vertica Schema or all tables in a schema from one physical cluster to another physical Cluster

Tags: schema, database-migration, vertica

I am trying to export and import Vertica schema from one physical cluster to another physical cluster.
My Test instance has one single cluster and my production instance has 3 clusters.

I explored following options, but they are limited to moving data on one physical Vertica instance:

1. EXPORT TO VERTICA ..
2. COPY schema.table FROM VERTICA ...

Would like to know if there is an option to move the Vertica schema from one physical Vertica instance to another, with different cluster configuration.

Comment: Do you want to migrate the **data** or the DDL of the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky manipulation, which have many issues:

- If you copy over DDLs, you will lose the current value of sequences, which might mean duplicate primary key when you insert data.
- If columns are set up as AUTO_INCREMENT, you will not be able to insert data in it as it is on the source (you cannot force an auto_increment column, although I believe this might have been fixed in new releases).
- If you copy DDLs between clusters with a different number of nodes, if node names are part of projection definition, you will end up with something you do not want.
- As you noticed, different networks will prevent the use of CONNECT.

An attempt to help out with this has been done in python via the [pyvertica](https://github.com/spilgames/pyvertica/) utility, and specially the [vertica_migrate](https://github.com/spilgames/pyvertica/blob/master/scripts/vertica_migrate) script. You can find the doc at https://pyvertica.readthedocs.org .

This is a tricky job, and I know there are some issues in this script, although it already helped me *a lot*.

Hope this helped,

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the resources, will keep you posted on the results

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [`COPY FROM VERTICA`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPYFROMVERTICA.htm) or [`EXPORT TO VERTICA`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/EXPORTTOVERTICA.htm) to import/export the data to another Vertica database (regardless of node configuration). Also, the target table must already exist. You can use [`EXPORT_OBJECTS`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/EXPORT_OBJECTS.htm) to export the DDL. Both methods allow for data migration from a version that's an earlier release from the last major release (running 6.x, you can import from 5.x).

In the example below, I'll use `EXPORT TO VERTICA` to export data from the source database to the target database.

You must first create a connection to the other database:

```
CONNECT TO VERTICA VMart USER dbadmin PASSWORD '' ON 'VerticaTarget',5433;
```

Then use `EXPORT TO VERTICA` to export the data from the source to the target database:

```
EXPORT TO VERTICA VMart.schema.customer_dimension FROM schema.customer_dimension;
                  |______________________________|     |_______________________|
                                 |                                 |
                              Target                            Source

DISCONNECT VMart;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Here is my issue, my production is on prod.abc.com and test is on test.abc.com servers, now i login to target machine which production using following command:
1. CONNECT TO VERTICA db USER user PASSWORD 'password' ON 'prod.abc.com',5433;
And now to move the data from test to production, how would I specify the server name in export to vertica command "test.abc.com"
2. EXPORT TO VERTICA db.schema1.table1 FROM 'test.abc.com'.testschema.table1;

Comment: Are both your instances on a private network? The database in which you executed the `CONNECT TO VERTICA` command is your *source*. At this point, you've already established the connection with the target. The only qualifiers are the ones that are explained in my answer.

Comment: Kermit, Thanks for your response. As i mentioned my test instance has one cluster and production has 3 clusters. I did try login into Test and tried exporting into production, but i get following issue now: ERROR 4534:  Receive on v_vertica_prod1_node0001: Message receipt from v_prod_db1_node0008 failed [Caught exception in readToQueue: VIAssert(validateHeader()) failed]

Comment: @bhargavreddy A cluster is a collection of nodes. Do you mean to say that you have a single test node and a 3 node production cluster? Are both instances on a private network?

Comment: Kermit, Sorry for incorrect usage, yes test has single node and production has 3 nodes and yes both the instances are on a private network.